# Compile::cplist: error from MapThread

Tags: warning-messages, compile

What is the cause of this error?

```
Compile[{{r, _Integer, 2}, {d, _Integer, 2}},
  pos = Position[MapThread[#1 > #2 &, {r, d}, 2], x_ /; x == True]]
```

> Compile::cplist: MapThread[#1 > #2&, {r, d}, 2] should be a tensor of type Integer, Real, or Complex; evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>

Comment: The error message tells you: the virtual machine does not support registers of tensor boolean type. See [this related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/function-does-not-compile-with-greater-in-it).

Comment: Thanks @OleksandrR. I will trying it without MapThread, and threading it by a loop.

Comment: Whichever method you attempt to use to produce a boolean list will fail in the VM, unfortunately, since this simply does not exist as a type. Perhaps, as in the linked question, you could produce a list of 1s and 0s instead of `True`s and `False`s?

Comment: Yes actually I have problem yet, there is some problem with ">" Greater , Also. @OleksandrR. MapThread is not the core of problem, I used it with Compile before.

Comment: I know. Seriously, please read the linked thread in detail. It discusses the very same problem as you're facing, and [Andy Ross's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1760/312) tells you what to do about it.

Comment: Thanks very much after some hours trying eventually it solved. as it came in down @OleksandrR.

Comment: Tangentially related: [(9831)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9831/121)

Answer (score 0):

```
Compile[{{r, _Integer, 2}, {d, _Integer, 2}},
 a = Position[Sign@MapThread[#1 - #2 &, {r, d}], 1]
 ]
```

Comment: when there is some error from using map in compile, with adding IntegerPart@ to the list that will be map, the error will not occur again. but why?

Comment: Regarding your comment, probably the compiler cannot tell what type the list will be and is expecting an Integer array.  You can often fix this by using a third argument in `Compile`; see the documentation for details.  Post a new question with a minimal self-contained example if you need help.