# Find positions of certain value in a big boolean list

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, boolean-computation

I would like to know is it possible to find positions of `False` in `t`:

```
t = Table[RandomChoice[{True, False}], 6000];
Flatten[Position[t, False]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

faster than the above method.
I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Speed here is hindered by the fact that `True`/`False` is [not a packable type](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9831/121) in *Mathematica*, although I personally think it should be.

If it is possible to reformulate your problem to use `1`/`0` instead, which can be packed, the methods already provided ([`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) and [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html)) each become much faster.

You can convert your data using [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) faster than using [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html), but the overhead is still significant:

```
SeedRandom[1]
t = Table[RandomChoice[{True, False}], 6000];

b = Developer`ToPackedArray @ 
      With[{True = 1, False = 0}, Evaluate @ t]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.000151, Null}
> ```

Now observe how fast `Pick` becomes compared to its direct application on `t`:

```
r1 = Pick[Range @ Length @ t, t, False]; // RepeatedTiming

r2 = Pick[Range @ Length @ b, b, 0]; // RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> ```
> {0.000343, Null}
>
> {0.0000509, Null}
>
> True
> ```

Combined with the overhead of the conversion this is a little slower than kglr's method (0.000176 second on my machine), but it gives an idea of the performance that is possible if you can avoid `True`/`False` and use packed integers instead.

Comment: Wow, I am really surprised that `With[{True = 1, False = 0}, Evaluate @ t]` is faster than `Boole`.

Comment: @Henrik It's kind of disappointing isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is... As well as the general slowness of Booleans in Mathematica.

Comment: @Henrik Yet another case where there is room for improvement in the core language that is neglected, all the while new functions applicable only for some are added.

Comment: *sigh* I am totally with you in that respect.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It's not just faster than `Boole`, it's also much faster than the equivalent `Replace[t, {True -> 1, False -> 0}, {1}]`.  Strange! I reported this to support.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick):

```
t = Table[RandomChoice[{True,False}],6000];
r1 = Flatten[Position[t,False]]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = Pick[Range@Length@t,t,False]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.0023, Null}
>
> {0.00036, Null}
>
> True

Another useful alternative is [`PositionIndex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex), especially when you want to know the positions of different values:

```
r3 = PositionIndex[t]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2 === r3[False]
```

> {0.00070, Null}
>
> True

Answer (score 6):

Using `SparseArray` with `"AdjacencyLists"` or with `"NonzeroPositions"` is faster than alternatives posted so far:

```
SeedRandom[1]
t = Table[RandomChoice[{True, False}], 6000];

r4 =SparseArray[t, Automatic, True]["AdjacencyLists"]; //RepeatedTiming  // First
```

> 0.00021

```
r5 = Flatten@SparseArray[t, Automatic, True]["NonzeroPositions"]; //RepeatedTiming// First
```

> 0.00021

versus

```
r1 = Flatten[Position[t, False]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0027

```
r2 = Pick[Range @ Length @ t, t, False]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.000414

```
r3 = PositionIndex[t][False]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.000830

```
(b = Developer`ToPackedArray @ With[{True =1, False =0}, Evaluate @ t]; 
 r6 = Pick[Range @ Length @ b, b, 0];) //RepeatedTiming  // First
```

> 0.00028

```
SameQ[r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6]
```

> True

where  `r1` is from OP, `r2` and `r3` are from Carl Woll's and `r6` is from Mr.Wizard's answer.