# Substituting 0 for even and 1 for odd natural numbers using EvenQ[]

Tags: replacement

I am trying to define a substitution that gives 1 for odd numbers and 0 for even numbers. My guess was (in a particular example)

`{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} /. N_Integer -> If[EvenQ[N], 0, 1]`

But the output is `{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}`. The problem is in `EvenQ[]` which is acting on a symbol, but I specified before that it should be applied only to integers, so I do not understand why it does not work.

Where is the problem? Does it have something to do with `->`?

Comment: Yes. Use `:>` instead of `->`. But then, why not use `Mod[list, 2]`?

Answer (score 7):

See JM's comment.  The following points in a somewhat more general direction for some queries.

```
Boole@OddQ@Range[0, 6]
```

Comment: It should be `Boole@OddQ@Range[0, 6]`

Answer (score 7):

In case speed matters `Mod` suggested by J.M. in comments is orders of magnitude faster than `ReplaceAll` and `Boole`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
input = RandomInteger[10^6, 10^6];
First[RepeatedTiming[res0 = input /. n_Integer :> If[EvenQ[n], 0, 1];]]
```

> 0.999

```
First[RepeatedTiming[ res1 = Boole@OddQ@input; ]]
```

> .0226

```
First[RepeatedTiming[res2 =  With[{True = 1, False = 0}, Evaluate@OddQ[input]]; ]]
```

> 0.048

```
First[RepeatedTiming[ res3 = Mod[input, 2];]]
```

> 0.00722

```
res0 == res1 == res2 == res3
> True
```

where the trick in `res2` is from [this answer by Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179808/125).

Comment: Nice trick!  (But it's disappointing.)