# Ways to speed up Pick

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, filtering

I have a few large arrays (100 times larger than in the example) and I need to re-arrange them.  Basically using tests on `b` and `c`, I need to pick elements of `a`.

```
a = RandomReal[1, 10^7];
b = RandomReal[1, 10^7];
c = RandomReal[1, 10^7];

sel = MapThread[(Abs[#1] <= 0.1) ∧ (Abs[#2] > 0.9)&, {b, c}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {10.9262,Null}

```
d = Pick[a, sel]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.584831,Null}

`MapThread` and `Pick` are the only ways to do this, as far as I found, I can't re-arrange the code any more.
The selection generation takes awhile, many times longer than on other platforms, is there a faster way to speed this up?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `UnitStep` to construct your selector array:

```
SeedRandom[1]
a = RandomReal[1, 10^7];
b = RandomReal[1, 10^7];
c = RandomReal[1, 10^7];

sel = MapThread[(Abs[#1] <= 0.1) ∧ (Abs[#2] > 0.9) &, {b, c}]; //
   AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 15.332532

```
d = Pick[a, sel]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.605384

```
sel2 = UnitStep[.1 - Abs[b]](1- UnitStep[.9 - Abs[c]]); // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.630973

```
d2 = Pick[a, sel2, 1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.015618

```
d == d2
```

> True

If `sel` is already created, you can convert it a packed array. Additional processing time to do this is more than compensated for by speed gains in `Pick`:

```
sel3 = Developer`ToPackedArray[With[{True = 1, False = 0}, Evaluate[sel]]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.37475

```
d3 = Pick[a, sel3, 1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.031245

```
d == d3
```

> True

See [this answer by Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179808/125) for the origin of the `With[{True = 1, False = 0}, ...]` trick.

**Update:** Slightly faster way to construct the selector array (thanks: Fred Simons):

```
With[{sel3 = UnitStep[.1 - Abs[b]] - UnitStep[0.9 - Abs[c]]}, 
 Pick[a, sel3, 1]]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to post. Always use vectorized functions if you can and always stay with machine integers/reals if you can. Furthermore, `sel` is not a packed array because `MapThread` doesn't pack automatically for some reason. That makes `MapThread` even less appealing.

Comment: One issue: you are effectively using `Abs[c] >= 0.9` and not `Abs[c] > 0.9` as OP requested.

Comment: @Sjoerd If you use this technique, check out BoolEval (see my answer).

Comment: @Szabolcs, thank you. I will update with a fix in a moment.

Comment: Replacing `True`/`False` with `1`/`0` is more easily done with `Boole`. It works on lists too.

Comment: @Szabolcs, yes but Mr.Wizard's method is much faster than `Boole`.

Comment: Thank you @kglr, this works !  Still not sure which functions are vectorized,and exactly how packing works, but this makes sense

Comment: A slight simplification of the `UnitStep` construction, speeding it up:
`With[{sel=UnitStep[.1-Abs[b]]+UnitStep[Abs[c]-0.9]}, Pick[a, sel,2]]`.

Comment: Thank you @FredSimons. I updated with variant  (to have `Abs[c] > 0.9`, not `Abs[c] >= 0.9` )  of your suggestion.

Answer (score 10):

@kglr already showed how to do this with vectorization, which offers much better performance.

However, the syntax with all those `UnitSteps` is not very friendly.  [My BoolEval package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2822/12) offers much better syntax for the very same operation.

Demo:

```
a = RandomReal[1, 10^7];
b = RandomReal[1, 10^7];
c = RandomReal[1, 10^7];
```

```
sel = MapThread[(Abs[#1] <= 0.1) ∧ (Abs[#2] > 0.9) &, {b, c}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {10.2691, Null} *)

d = Pick[a, sel]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.460785, Null} *)
```

```
<< BoolEval`

e = BoolPick[a, Abs[b] <= 0.1 && Abs[c] > 0.9]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.186719, Null} *)
```

```
e == d
(* True *)
```

We went from ~11 seconds to only 0.18 s, while shortening the code to a very readable one-liner.  I hope this already convinced you that you really need BoolEval ;-)

I should also point out that @kglr's solution actually uses `Abs[c] >= 0.9` and not `Abs[c] > 0.9` as you requested. To achieve a true `>`, we could use `1 - UnitStep[0.9 - Abs[c]]`, which would make the code even less readable. BoolEval takes care of this for you.

One more thing to note:

`Pick` is much faster if the second argument is [a packed array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) and the third argument is a simple number (not the default `True`).

Comment: Yes, matlab notation is what I am used to, this will help keep my mind straight when I go between the two, thank you!!